# haben sie mir oder für mich

Tags: german-to-english

> "Haben sie mir einen Brief?"

or

> "Haben sie einen Brief für mich?"

Comment: In general, it helps if you make it clear which language you're asking the question in. This helps people decide in which language to write the answer. You have everything but one word in German, but it looks like you're more comfortable with English. If you are more comfortable with German make the whole question in German, otherwise quote German phrases when necessary and use English for the rest, so use or instead of oder. Also, use complete sentences either way: Should I use "Haben sie mir einen Brief?" or "Haben sie einen Brief für mich?"

Comment: I don’t know what the reason for the down-vote was but I would ask people to consider that dative case may be unusual for people coming from other languages and that it may therefore be difficult to judge which functions it can fulfill.

Answer (score 1):

It's "Haben Sie einen Brief für mich?"

If you live in the southern part of the German language area you could maybe ask someone for e.g. borrowing a pen by asking: "Haben Sie mir einen Stift?", but I wouldn't call that standard German, and it also somehow doesn't work for asking for letters that are already addressed to you.

Comment: In the "southern part of the German language area" - that is: in Austria and the Southern Tyrol - i never ever heard "Haben Sie mir einen Stift?" or any analogous construction. Do you have any source for this claim?

Comment: @bakunin See for example [this collection of sayings, songs etc.](https://www.schwaebischer-dialekt.de/forschungPDF/gnugHaihunta.pdf) from Upper Swabia: "Hosch mer en Hugo?", "Hast du mir einen Hugo?" (with "Hugo" referring to a cigarette). Or [this source about Bavarian and Alemannic dialects](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/server/api/core/bitstreams/4f8ca378-6482-49d6-8cef-bf154c7ebbfa/content): "Hesch mer a bier zum trinke", "hast-du mir ein Bier zu-trinken". I've studied neither source in detail, but I'd reckon them good enough to prove this construction exists.

Comment: Can confirm for Schwaben.

Answer (score 1):

The verb *haben* does not take a dative object, so it must be

> Haben Sie einen Brief für mich?

Mind the caps on *Sie*!

In general, the dative object tells who has to bear the result of the action, most times that means who benefits from it. Your thinking is correct from your point of view. Because you ask for a letter that is for you, you would benefit from having it.

**But you aren't having it yet.** The subject has it. If someone **has** something, no one but that someone bears the "result" of that action.